# Java FMJ is not cross platfrom ? How can it be fixed?

Tags: java, javafx, jmf, fmj

I was trying to use FMJ (for windows/linux/mac). Where JMF was not working for me (so decided to work with FMJ as it is cross platform). But when ever i am trying FMJ it never works, where you can see the difference in the screen shot.

[image]

Note: I have two cameras connected in the same PC and Flash detects always both of them without any issue. But FMJ is never working?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the UnsatisfiedLinkException native code is used, and it is not set correctly up for your Linux box or the required binary is simply not there.

Comment: I want to thank you. What i was facing is Flash/Flex does not care what Fmj is now facing, its never like plug and play, which is a bad end user experience.  In this screen shot i know there is a missing libraries but how Flash didnt required it but Fmj failed ? ex: http://i.imgur.com/AjcJh.png

Comment: Yes, http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/stratus/stratus_app_article_assets_update.zip

Comment: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/#resources  if you compare this use experience and Fmj installation experience. You will find much easy to use the Flash one. But how can Fmj be as simple as possible to install in cross platform atleast ? Like cirrus does.

Comment: @Stackfan, if this kind of errors are unfamiliar to you, you will probably not find any Java+JNI solution fun, and you should probably go for another solution.

Comment: But can you see the differences where Flash start just like plug and play. But JMF/FMJ all other Java video frameworks does not get started just in the way plug and play should be. Is there no other solution for Java to have it solved either installing missing libraries or failed libraries using jnlp etc etc..

Answer (score 1):

It says it can not find libstdc++, I had similar problem with another lib, installing g++ helped. Try that.